# 500 error when Azure AD B2C calls signin-oidc callback

Tags: azure, authentication, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I am writing an ASP.Net Core 2.0 web app and I'm trying to use Azure AD B2C for the authentication.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

  JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

  services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
      options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
      options.DefaultSignInScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
      options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
      options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com";
      options.Audience = "aud";
      options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
      {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = t =>
        {
          return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
      };
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
      options.MetadataAddress = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Tenant"]}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p={Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Policy"]}";
      options.ClientId = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientId"];
      options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents { OnAuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed, OnTokenValidated = Validated, OnRemoteFailure = Failed };
      options.SaveTokens = true;
    });

  services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
  {
    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
      .AllowAnyMethod()
      .AllowAnyHeader()
      .AllowCredentials();
  }));

  services.AddMvc();

  services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
  {
    options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("MyPolicy"));
  });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
  app.UseAuthentication();

  if (env.IsDevelopment())
  {
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    builder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();

    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
    {
      HotModuleReplacement = true,
        ReactHotModuleReplacement = true
    });
  }
  else
  {
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
  }

  app.UseStaticFiles();
  app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
  app.UseMvc();
}
```

I have an `[Authorize]` attribute on a controller action and when I follow the link I get presented with the Microsoft login page.  I login successfully and it redirects me back to `https://localhost:[PORT]/signin-oidc` which returns a 500 server error.

My question is does anyone know why this is happening?  I thought it might be something to do with CORS but it doesnt look like it.  The post from Microsoft seems to contain a valid token.

Comment: You will need to debug the issue more. A 500 error could mean anything. Though by they way, your JWT Bearer auth is configured wrong. The authority does not point to a proper authority, and the audience should be the client id / App ID URI.

Comment: If you add a breakpoint on `OnAuthenticationFailed`, does it get hit? If so, inspect `t` and see if it has more details.

Comment: I've added breakpoints on OnAuthenticationFailed but it doesn't get hit.  Any suggestions on what else I can do to debug?

Comment: I´m having the "same" problem when posting into `/oidc-signin` as the return from AD with the token. The interesting thing in my case is that it's happening only when deployed in a QA environment, not in DEV, not in local. I am seeing a javascript error `The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared`. Did you manage to debug the problem? Which `OpenIdConnectEvents`'s event did you use to access the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio Debug window usually has some useful information to help troubleshoot.

---

I would change your startup code to match [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapi/blob/58467e7f51208f137405a3fb29fb3bc535cf11d9/B2C-WebApi/Startup.cs#L39) (remove the call to `AddOpenIdConnect()`):

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions =>
    {
      jwtOptions.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Tenant"]}/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Policy"]}/v2.0/";
      jwtOptions.Audience = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientId"];
      jwtOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
      {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed
      };
});
```

---

I would also add a handler to `OnMessageReceived` in `JwtBearerEvents`.  Put a breakpoint on that handler and see if you are getting that far.